# NuGet package update - Package Manager found another package with same name

Tags: visual-studio, package, nuget

I'm quite new to NuGet Package building and publishing so maybe there's something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what is it.

I have a VS2022 solution which contains my reference projects. "Project A" is being published locally on my network as a NuGet package (not on nuget.org).

Another solution which I'm currently working on, uses that Project A package via NuGet. The problem is: on NuGet.org there's another package with the same name, so when I open Package Manager window the Update tab shows me an available update for that project - but that's not my package because it comes from nuget.org.
The "silly fix" is obviusly to change package source from the combobox, instead of "All" I set "local" and then the correct package is found.

What am I missing here?
Project A is set with "sign package" on properties, if that matters.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: I appreciate your help but provided solution does not solve the problem, although it's still a workaround.

Comment: Do the two packages meant to be the same "thing"? Or is your local one unrelated to the one on NuGet.org?

Comment: @Kit They are completely unrelated, the same name is just a coincidence.

Comment: The problem is that NuGet does its package checking by *name* across sources. I think you're just going to have to change your name. Because they are both the same, their versions seem entangled (when you check version dropdown, I bet your version numbers and theirs are there). Another--distasteful in my opinion--way to do it is to set your packages to a ridiculously higher version number so your versions appear to be the ones to upgrade to... but this is REALLY fighting the system.

Comment: I thought nuget managed to recognize packages with other methods but probably I was wrong. At this point it seems the only solution is something like adding a prefix to my package name.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to change the name of your Project A, it will be a good choice to solve this problem.

If you don't use the packages from nuget.org you can uncheck this source in Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Source:
[image]

You can search the version of your package like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I'd like not changing package name, and I have to keep both sources active (nuget.org and local directory) because I have dependencies from both. I thing there should be another way...

Comment: If you don't want to change the package name but it conflicts with the package name on nuget.org. I think the method you said to modify the package source to a local source is simple and effective. Or you can search the version for your package like the image I will update in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I already defined two NuGet sources but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: Changing the name is really the only way to go I think. @privatefrank see my comments on your question. The only other real option I can see is that you have a private internal feed to your organization that filters out *specific* packages from external feeds, but that way is fraught with major headaches (e.g. what if someone needs yours *and* theirs)?